# Invalid ModelState error message for Nullable types

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I validate the input using `ModelState.IsValid`:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("subjects")]
[ValidateAttribute]
public IHttpActionResult GetSubjects(bool? isActive = null)
{
    //get subjects
}
```

If I pass in the uri `~/subjects/?isActive=abcdef`, I get the error message:

> The value 'abcdef' is not valid for Nullable`1.

If the input parameter is not nullable

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSubjects(bool isActive){
   //get subjects
}
```

I get the error message:

> The value 'abcdef' is not valid for Boolean.

I want to override the message if nullable type so I can maintain the message ("The value 'abcdef' is not valid for Boolean."). How can I do this since in the `ModelState` error I don't get the data type. I am implementing the validation as a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` (`ValidationAttribute`).

Comment: You can set any error message you want in `ModelState`.

Comment: I can set it to what I want like "The value 'abcdef' is not valid for Boolean.", but the problem is the error object does not have the type information(bool, int, etc) of the parameter being validated.

Answer (score 2):

You can change callback that formats type conversion error messages. For example, let's define it right into `Global.asax.cs`:

```cs
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ModelBinderConfig.TypeConversionErrorMessageProvider = this.NullableAwareTypeConversionErrorMessageProvider;

        // rest of your initialization code
    }

    private string NullableAwareTypeConversionErrorMessageProvider(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, object incomingValue)
    {
        var target = modelMetadata.PropertyName;
        if (target == null)
        {
            var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(modelMetadata.ModelType) ?? modelMetadata.ModelType;
            target = type.Name;
        }

        return string.Format("The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}", incomingValue, target);
    }
}
```

For not nullable types `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` will return null, in this case we will use original type.

Unfortunately you cannot access default string resources and if you need to localize error message you must do it on your own.

Another way is to implement your own `IModelBinder`, but this is not a good idea for your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lorond's answer highlights how flexible asp.net web api is in terms of letting a programmer customize many parts of the API. When I looked at this question, my thought process was to handle it in an action filter rather than overriding something in the configuration.

```cs
public class ValidateTypeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ValidateTypeAttribute() { }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string somebool = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Where(x => x.Key.ToString() == "somebool").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        bool outBool;
        //do something if somebool is empty string
        if (!bool.TryParse(somebool, out outBool))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            response.ReasonPhrase = "The value " + somebool + " is not valid for Boolean.";
            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

Then decorate the action method in the controller with the action filter attribute

Comment: "somebool" is hardcoded here. since it will be an attribute that i need to use heavily in different controllers, we dont know the parameter name and the nullable parameter type(bool?, int?), so i cant hard code the parameter name and the type.

Comment: You could bypass with a type test.